# Lock screen for an application

Tags: android, security, android-edittext, passwords

I am trying to secure my application using a lock screen using user inputkey, first time user will enter a 5 digit key as password and again enter same and confirm the password in different views,i don't have no idea to confirm the password,

How about shared preference or intent?

This is my design

[image]

**Source code:**

```
public class LockscreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private EditText mPasswordField;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lockscreen);
        initViews();
        getInputText();

    }
    private void initViews() {
        mPasswordField = $(R.id.password_field);
        $(R.id.t9_key_0).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_1).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_2).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_3).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_4).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_5).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_6).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_7).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_8).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_9).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_clear).setOnClickListener(this);
        $(R.id.t9_key_backspace).setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // handle number button click
        if (v.getTag() != null && "number_button".equals(v.getTag())) {
            mPasswordField.append(((TextView) v).getText());
            return;
        }
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.t9_key_clear: { // handle clear button
//                mPasswordField.setText(null);

                String a=getInputText();
                Toast.makeText(LockscreenActivity.this,a,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            break;
            case R.id.t9_key_backspace: { // handle backspace button
                // delete one character
                Editable editable = mPasswordField.getText();
                int charCount = editable.length();
                if (charCount > 0) {
                    editable.delete(charCount - 1, charCount);
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    public String getInputText() {
        return mPasswordField.getText().toString();

    }

    protected <T extends View> T $(@IdRes int id) {
        return (T) super.findViewById(id);
    }

}
```

Comment: Please refer to this: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html DO NOT store the key in shared preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the entered password in shared preference and then compare it with next entered password.

```
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
    editor.putString("first_entered", "password");
    editor.apply();
    //To retrieve values from shared preferences:
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String name = preferences.getString("first_entered", "");
    if (name.equals("next_input_entered")) {
        //password matched
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local string variable which will be appended on every input in this part of your code

```
    String inputPin = "";
    if (v.getTag() != null && "number_button".equals(v.getTag())) {
        mPasswordField.append(((TextView) v).getText());
        inputPin = inputPin + ((TextView) v).getText();
        return;
    }
```

Then when your repeat pin view is shown, you can store that pin in another variable and then match it.
Since you have two views in same activity, you will be able to use some variable defined at the activity.